# Maximum number of users returned per page when calling transitive member api on a group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following query to get the transitive members in a group:

```
await _graphServiceClient
                                .Groups[groupId]
                                .TransitiveMembers
                                .Request()
                                .Top(999)
                                .GetAsync();
```

For larger groups, response takes a longer time as there are a number of pages being returned. Currently I have set the top value as 999. What is the maximum number of users that can be returned per page?

Comment: I guess it is 999. Have you tried to set Top(1000)? You can easily find the maximum size that will work for you.

Comment: Looks like it's 999. Is there a way to get more number of users per page instead?

Comment: What's the goal? Time or number of requests? When you try https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupId/transitiveMembers?$top=1000 in Graph Explorer you will receive the error: Invalid page size specified: '1000'. Must be between 1 and 999 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum allowed value can vary depending on the kind of collection you're going to ask. Most of them have a maximum value of 999 by using top(999), but a few have lower values (If you pick a too high number you get back an error message containing the maximum allowed value).

The retrieved page object has a property NextPageRequest which will be not null, if further data is available and you can get it by calling it:

```
var moreMembers = await members.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
```

You can do this in a while loop, till the property NextPageRequest is null to get a list of all members.

Similar issue - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/13233

Hope this help

Thanks

Comment: In the provided link there is the comment that max. number is 999? Where did you find 1000?

Comment: sorry , you can query upto 999 , edited my comment . Thanks